# Django select 2 multiple select slow load

Tags: django, jquery-select2

I'm a beginner and I've been playing around with the multiple select option of select2.js.  In a historical school database we have over 300k student_id's.  I can get the select2 option to work, but it's extremely slow and takes forever to load.  I've seen other pages with select 2 load massive amounts of data and work fine.

I'm using the following to javascript to load select2.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
  });
```

In Django i'm loading the data in my template with:

```
  <script src= "{% static '/search/user_select2.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>

             <div class="col"><h4 style="margin-top: 0"><strong>Student ID List</strong></h4><select data-placeholder="Choose a list of 3-4 User ids..." class="js-example-basic-multiple"  value = "{{ userid }}" style="width: 1110px" required>
             {% for user in userid %}
             <option value="{{ user }}"> {{ user }}</option>
             {% endfor %}
           </select>
```

userid is defined with the following arg in my view:

```
def multisearch(request):
    userid = STudent.objects.filter(student_status_id = 1).values('studentid')
    print(userid)

    args = {'userid':userid}

    return render(request, 'multisearch.html',args)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It takes a long time to load be cause you preload all options of your select2 input. I would suggest you to use select2 through [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to avoid this issue. It will provide you tools to setup an autocomplete system and load matching options while typing text on your select2 input. Moreover, results paginated so that they are loaded as you scroll the select2 dropdown.

Basically you will have an autocomplete view:

```
from dal import autocomplete

from your_app.models import Student


class Status1StudentsAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Student.objects.filter(student_status_id=1)
        if self.q:  # self.q is the user-typed query
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)
        return qs
```

That, of course, needs to be routed:

```
from your_app.views import Status1StudentsAutocomplete

urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^autocomplete/students/status-1/$',
        Status1StudentsAutocomplete.as_view(),
        name='students_status1_autocomplete',
    ),
]
```

Then use an autocomplete widget for your field:

```
from dal import autocomplete

from django import forms


class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    student = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Student.objects.filter(student_status_id=1),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='student_status1_autocomplete')
    )
```

Finally just display your form as you usually would and don't forget to include the custom css/js with `{{ form.media }}`.

```
{% extend "your_layout.html" %}
{% block extrahead %} {# assuming extrahead block is within the <head> element #}
    {{ block.super }}
    {{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %} {# assuming you have a content block within your <body> element #}
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="submit">Go!</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What would i use with django-autocomplete-light to improve the performance?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer to give more details about how django autocomplete light will help you.

Comment: Thank you Antoine.

Comment: Unfortunately django-autocomplete-light appears to be down.   Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages
urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025D48D755C0>, 'Connection to files.pythonhosted.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')
: /packages/ee/2c/8830276bfdb01713486585640125e0b6d0f2b4ee2ece96689a846c3d77cc/django-autocomplete-light-3.2.10.tar.gz

Comment: Likely a temporary issue with pythonhosted.org.

Comment: Ignore that comment above.  I was able to fix it by adding "dal" and "dal_select2" to the INSTALLED_APPS.